# Show transformed value in LabeledSlider?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

The example below is just a simple toy for the sake of this question.

The widget shown below uses a slider to set the horizontal location of a vertical line:

```
Module[
 {X},
 Manipulate[
  Module[{x = X},
   Show[
    Graphics[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 20}}]],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 20}},
    Frame -> True,
    AspectRatio -> Automatic
    ]
   ],
  {{X, 50}, 0, 100, 1, LabeledSlider}
  ]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that, as one moves the slider, its current value is displayed at the right of it.

Suppose, however, that one wanted to display the log10 of this value instead.

One could do this

```
Module[
 {log10x},
 Manipulate[
  Module[{x = 10^log10x},
   Show[
    Graphics[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 20}}]],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 20}},
    Frame -> True,
    AspectRatio -> Automatic
    ]
   ],
  {{log10x, N@Log10[50]}, -2, 2, 0.1, LabeledSlider}
  ]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In this version, the log10 of the value is displayed, but the relationship between the slider's movement and the position of the vertical line is no longer uniform throughout the slider's range: the vertical line accelerates (relative to the slider) as the slider approaches its rightmost limit <sup>1</sup>.

**Questions:**

1. How can I retain the first version's uniform relationship between the slider's motion and the position of the vertical line, but show the log10 of the value next to the slider?
2. How can I control the string to the left of the slider?  (to display, for example, `Log10 of x`, instead of `log10x$4159`?)

---

**NB:** I have not been able to find any documentation at all for `LabeledSlider`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Alternatively, the position of the slider relative to its endpoints does not correspond to the position of the vertical line relative to the plot's horizontal range.  For example, in the second figure shown, the slider is close to its rightmost end, while the vertical line is midway along its range.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Manipulate[
    Show[
        Graphics[Line[{{x,0},{x,20}}]],
        PlotRange->{{0,100},{0,20}},Frame->True,AspectRatio->Automatic
    ],
    Row[{
        Control@{{x, 50., "log10x"}, 0.1, 100, 0.1, AppearanceElements->None},
        Dynamic[Log10[x]]
    }]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to change the value to the right, but the label to the left should work like this

```
     Manipulate[
 Module[{x = 10^log10x}, 
  Show[Graphics[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 20}}]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 20}}, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]], {{log10x, N@Log10[50], 
   "Log10 of X"}, -2, 2, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```